# Echarts: cdn version without the need for require.js or amd

Tags: cdn, echarts

Is it possible to have a customized version of echarts-all.js (baidu), as cdn without the need for require.js or amd loading?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?
http://www.bootcdn.cn/echarts/

Eharts don't have an offical CDN version.